# the name of "Granger causality" is correct?

Tags: terminology, granger-causality

"Granger causality" is different from general and actual causation, as far as I see it's description.

It seems just the method to select explanatory variables.

Is the name of "causality" correct? Why isn't it the name of selection variables? 
I think that this confuse people.

Comment: Why do you say it is a method for selecting explanatory variables? Per definition, it is a method of examining whether the past of $X$ helps predict $Y$ beyond the knowledge contained in the past of $Y$.

Comment: In any case, it is generally accepted nomenclature. Trying to replace it with something else will likely be much more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read Dr. Granger's paper yourself https://www.jstor.org/stable/1912791. He says:

> The definition of causality used [in this paper] is based entirely on the
>   predictability of some series, say $X_t$. If some other series $Y_t$ ,
>   contains information in past terms that helps in the prediction of $X_{t}$
>   and if this information is contained in no other series used in the
>   predictor, then $Y_t$ is said to cause $X_t$.

So no, it does not jive with any of the causality that was later developed by Rubin, Pearl, Hernan, etc. Merely predicting a future series based on a history of covariate values can be done successfully in non-causal settings. What's lacking is a) subject/content expertise b) a diagram representing the causal relation of possible confounders, colliders, and/or mediators (among other things). For instance, experience of a heart attack can predict a lower blood pressure (following administration of statins), so they Granger cause, but it'd be rather stupid to report that.

Comment: i see, can i understand to not yet exist exactly definition of "statistical causality" when published paper in 1969 ?

Comment: @cartman indeed. I would say it's still in contention, but the notion of a potential outcomes, counterfactual, and a "do" operator preclude simple prediction in time conditional on covariate history.

Comment: thank you, i didn't know about "statistical causality", but i had a little wider view to you.